# Facebook Sharing of same link shows differently in mobile devices and desktop

Tags: facebook, mobile, sdk

Hello I am trying to share some image in Facebook with javascript SDK.
But I am getting two defferent images for the same link.
Anyone have any idea?
[Link](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=your_app_id&description=And%20thus%2C%20this%20Raksha%20Bandhan%2C%20too%2C%20the%20epic%20banter%20between%20brothers%20and%20sisters%20continues.%20%20Want%20to%20join%20the%20fun%3F%20%20Click%20here%20to%20make%20your%20own%20fun%20card.&picture=http%3A%2F%2F182.72.159.116%3A8083%2Fget-user-image%3Ffile%3D1440396659347.png&title=&display=popup&href=http%3A%2F%2F182.72.159.116%3A8083%2F%3Fshow-sister%3Dfalse%23meme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F182.72.159.116%3A8083%2F%3Fshow-sister%3Dfalse%23meme)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Share dialog is not supposed to take additional parameters beside the URL to share any more; everything else will be taken from the OG meta tags of the URL. If you want to specify those values at runtime, you can use the Feed dialog.

Comment: But it works with desktop browsers.

Comment: And feed works with both. thank you for the suggestion